# Finding Duplicated Values in Pandas Groupby Object

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-science, aggregation

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

| msg_id | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Stackoverflow |
| 001 | Stackoverflow |
| 002 | Stackoverflow |
| 002 | Cross-Validated |

I want to drop the duplicated values in `identifier` for each unique value of `msg_id`

This is my current apporach which is super slow:

```py
acc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for _, group in df.groupby("msg_id"):
    df = group[group.duplicated("identifier")]
    if len(df) > 0:
        acc_df = pd.concat([df, acc_df], axis=0, ignore_index=False)
acc_df
```

I have a very large dataset with 500 million rows. Even after filtering for the `msg_id` that has more than one `identifier` comes at the very large number.

I am looking for any vectorized or faster apporach NOT INCLUDING **Multi-Processing** and **Threading**

Comment: The results of `acc_df` in your code are a little different from your explanation. can you provide your desired output?

Comment: Hi Panda Kim nice name. The `acc_df` shows all the duplicated entries as if we do `df.groupby("msg_id").duplicated("identifier")`

Comment: Is it correct that acc_df only has 1 row? And it is always good to attach the desired output as a table.

Comment: Yes in this case the `acc_df` only has one row, which is the second row in the above DataFrame.

Comment: Don't `groupby` just `drop_duplicates(subset=["msg_id", "identifier"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

The problem is to find rows where the values of two columns are duplicated, not grouped. This is possible as follows.

```
df[df.duplicated(['msg_id', 'identifier'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorized operations in Pandas rather than using explicit loops, which should be faster than your current approach.

```
data = {
    'msg_id': ['001', '001', '002', '002'],
    'identifier': ['Stackoverflow', 'Stackoverflow', 'Stackoverflow', 'Cross-Validated']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(['msg_id', 'identifier'], inplace=True)
df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(subset=['msg_id', 'identifier'], keep='first')
result = df[~df['is_duplicated']].drop(columns=['is_duplicated'])
```

Comment: That's not the ideal approach. Sorting is useless here, using a temporary column as well.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this answer (and others from you) was generated by an AI